# how to capture the screen of the active browser without other windows at the bottom of the taskbar

Tags: java, screen, screen-capture, awtrobot

While trying to capture the screen shot only from the active browser/window, other windows or other opened applications(minimized) at the bottom of the screen are displayed on the task bar.

So how to capture only from the active/cursor focused browser and ignore other windows at the bottom on the task in the screen shot

The following is the code what i have written so far to capture screen shot, but it still captures the other open applications in the screen shot.

```
    Dimension d = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    int width = (int) d.getWidth();
    int height = (int) d.getHeight();


    Image image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, width,
            height));

     BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
     Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
     g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);


     String fileNameToSaveTo = "D:/Pictures/" + PictureName + "_"
            + createTimeStampStr() + ".PNG";

     writeImage(bi, fileNameToSaveTo, "PNG");

     System.out.println("Screen Captured Successfully and Saved       to:\n"+fileNameToSaveTo);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to not capture the entire screen but only the rectangle that holds your window of interest. To get this window though, you'll need to go beyond Java, such as by using a 3rd party utility, or via JNI or JNA. I have successfully done this using JNA. I'd post my code, but it's in large project of more than 100 classes.

I can show some specific classes and interfaces that I use, but they are old and not "professional quality" by any means:

User32.java

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD.LONG_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
   User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

   interface WNDENUMPROC extends StdCallCallback {
      boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg);
   }

   public static final int GW_OWNER = 4; // used with GetWindow to get win owner
   public static final int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2; // used with GetNextWindow
   public static final int GA_ROOT = 2; // used with GetAncestor
   public static final int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20; // used with GetWindowLong
   public static final long WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000L;
   public static final Pointer HWND_TOP = new Pointer(0L); // used with
                                                           // SetWindowPos

   boolean EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer userData);

   int GetWindowTextA(Pointer hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

   int SetForegroundWindow(Pointer hWnd);

   Pointer GetForegroundWindow();

   boolean GetWindowRect(Pointer hWnd, RECT rect);

   boolean SetWindowPos(Pointer hWnd, Pointer hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y,
         int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

   boolean MoveWindow(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, boolean bRepaint);

   boolean IsWindow(Pointer hWnd);

   Pointer GetWindow(Pointer hWnd, int uCmd);

   LONG_PTR GetWindowLongPtr(HWND hWnd, int nIndex);

   Pointer GetParent(Pointer hWnd);

   Pointer GetAncestor(Pointer hWnd, int gaFlags);

   boolean IsWindowVisible(Pointer hWnd);
}
```

JnaUtilException.java

```
public class JnaUtilException extends Exception {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public JnaUtilException(String text) {
      super(text);
   }

}
```

JnaUtil.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD.LONG_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;

/**
 * static methods to allow Java to call Windows code. user32.dll code is as
 * specified in the JNA interface User32.java
 * 
 * @author Pete S
 * 
 */
public class JnaUtil {
   private static final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
   private static Pointer callBackHwnd;

   public static boolean windowExists(final String startOfWindowName) {
      return !user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer userData) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();

            if (!wText.isEmpty() && wText.startsWith(startOfWindowName)) {
               return false;
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);
   }

   public static List<String> getAllWindowNames() {
      final List<String> windowNames = new ArrayList<String>();
      user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {

         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();
            if (!wText.isEmpty()) {
               windowNames.add(wText);
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);

      return windowNames;
   }

   public static boolean windowExists(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.IsWindow(hWnd);
   }

   public static Pointer getWinHwnd(final String startOfWindowName) {
      callBackHwnd = null;

      user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer userData) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();

            if (!wText.isEmpty() && wText.startsWith(startOfWindowName)) {
               callBackHwnd = hWnd;
               return false;
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);
      return callBackHwnd;
   }

   public static boolean setForegroundWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd) != 0;
   }

   public static Pointer getForegroundWindow() {
      return user32.GetForegroundWindow();
   }

   public static String getForegroundWindowText() {
      Pointer hWnd = getForegroundWindow();
      int nMaxCount = 512;
      byte[] lpString = new byte[nMaxCount];
      int getWindowTextResult = user32
            .GetWindowTextA(hWnd, lpString, nMaxCount);
      if (getWindowTextResult == 0) {
         return "";
      }

      return Native.toString(lpString);
   }

   public static boolean isForegroundWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetForegroundWindow().equals(hWnd);
   }

   public static boolean setForegroundWindow(String startOfWindowName) {
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(startOfWindowName);
      return user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd) != 0;
   }

   public static Rectangle getWindowRect(Pointer hWnd) throws JnaUtilException {
      if (hWnd == null) {
         throw new JnaUtilException(
               "Failed to getWindowRect since Pointer hWnd is null");
      }
      Rectangle result = null;
      RECT rect = new RECT();
      boolean rectOK = user32.GetWindowRect(hWnd, rect);
      if (rectOK) {
         int x = rect.left;
         int y = rect.top;
         int width = rect.right - rect.left;
         int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
         result = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
      }

      return result;
   }

   /**
    * set window at x and y position with w and h width. Set on top of z-order
    * 
    * @param hWnd
    * @param x
    * @param y
    * @param w
    * @param h
    * @return boolean -- did it work?
    */
   public static boolean setWindowPos(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
      int uFlags = 0;
      return user32.SetWindowPos(hWnd, User32.HWND_TOP, x, y, w, h, uFlags);
   }

   public static boolean moveWindow(Pointer hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth,
         int nHeight) {
      boolean bRepaint = true;
      return user32.MoveWindow(hWnd, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, bRepaint );
   }

   public static Rectangle getWindowRect(String startOfWindowName)
         throws JnaUtilException {
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(startOfWindowName);
      if (hWnd != null) {
         return getWindowRect(hWnd);
      } else {
         throw new JnaUtilException("Failed to getWindowRect for \""
               + startOfWindowName + "\"");
      }
   }

   public static Pointer getWindow(Pointer hWnd, int uCmd) {
      return user32.GetWindow(hWnd, uCmd);
   }

   public static String getWindowText(Pointer hWnd) {
      int nMaxCount = 512;
      byte[] lpString = new byte[nMaxCount];
      int result = user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, lpString, nMaxCount);
      if (result == 0) {
         return "";
      }
      return Native.toString(lpString);
   }

   public static Pointer getOwnerWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetWindow(hWnd, User32.GW_OWNER);
   }

   public static String getOwnerWindow(String childTitle) {
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(childTitle);
      Pointer parentHWnd = getOwnerWindow(hWnd);
      if (parentHWnd == null) {
         return "";
      }
      return getWindowText(parentHWnd);

   }

   public static Pointer getNextWindow(Pointer hWnd) {
      if (hWnd == null) {
         return null;
      }

      return user32.GetWindow(hWnd, User32.GW_HWNDNEXT);
   }

   public static boolean isWindowVisible(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.IsWindowVisible(hWnd);
   }

   public static Pointer getParent(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetParent(hWnd);
   }

   public static Pointer getRoot(Pointer hWnd) {
      return user32.GetAncestor(hWnd, User32.GA_ROOT);
   }

   public static LONG_PTR getWindowLongPtr(Pointer hWndP, int nIndex) {
      HWND hwnd = new HWND(hWndP);
      return user32.GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, nIndex);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      List<String> winNameList = getAllWindowNames();
      for (String winName : winNameList) {
         System.out.println(winName);
      }

      String[] testStrs = { "Untitled-Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad",
            "Untitled  -  Notepad", "Java-Epic", "Java - Epic", "Fubars rule!",
            "The First Night", "New Tab", "Citrix X", "EHR PROD - SVC" };
      for (String testStr : testStrs) {
         Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(testStr);
         boolean isWindow = windowExists(hWnd);
         System.out.printf("%-22s %5b %16s %b%n", testStr,
               windowExists(testStr), hWnd, isWindow);
      }

      String ehrProd = "EHR PROD - SVC";
      Pointer hWnd = getWinHwnd(ehrProd);
      System.out
            .println("is it foreground window? " + isForegroundWindow(hWnd));
      boolean foo = setForegroundWindow(ehrProd);
      System.out.println("foregroundwindow: " + foo);
      Thread.sleep(400);
      System.out
            .println("is it foreground window? " + isForegroundWindow(hWnd));
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("here A");
      try {
         Rectangle rect = getWindowRect(ehrProd);
         System.out.println("rect: " + rect);
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         System.out.println("here B");

         BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
         System.out.println("here C, img is " + img);
         Thread.sleep(500);
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
         System.out.println("here D. icon is null? " + icon);
         Thread.sleep(500);
         final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
         System.out.println("here E. label is null? " + label);
         Thread.sleep(500);
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               System.out.println("here F");               
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
               System.out.println("here G");
            }
         });

      } catch (AWTException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (JnaUtilException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

The method `JnaUtil.getWindowRect(hWnd);` gets the rectangle and is used like so:

```
  new SwingWorker<Void, ImageIcon>() {

     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Pointer hWnd = JnaUtil.getWinHwnd(winText);

        if (hWnd == null) {

           String errTxt = "Application Window \"" + winText
                 + "\" not open. Try again";
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pollingGui.getMainPanel(), errTxt,
                 "App Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return null;
        }

        try {
           rect = JnaUtil.getWindowRect(hWnd);
           fullWindowText = JnaUtil.getWindowText(hWnd);
```

Comment: Some little warning light in my head told me that this was too application & OS specific (not the author of the question) :)

Comment: @owlstead: you are correct, but to solve this problem, I think that the OP will be forced to get closer to the OS, which is why Java by itself is not enough. Any solution of this sort will be platform specific.

Comment: Hi Hovercraft. Thanks a lot for the reply. Could you please elaborate a little more about it and what API from JNA was useful.

Comment: @Steve: first off, what platform is this being run on? Windows? Unix?

Comment: Hi. It is on windows. The requirement from the client was to capture the screen from IE browser and compare it with FireFox capture

Comment: @Steve: i will post some of my code, but again, it's not professional grade by any means -- no unit testing for one -- but it has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hovercraft. I will look into it and test it by self and then proceed. By the way, is it a good idea to compare screenshot of a page from IE browser with screenshot of same page in FireFox /Chrome browser

Comment: @Steve: that sounds like a bad idea to me. Two browsers can almost be expected to show the same page in different ways. What kind of image analysis are you going to use to allow you to make sensible comparisons?